# Javascript Function returns undefined after for-loop runs the first time

Tags: javascript

I have a basic question about for-loops and variables. I have the following code:

```
function fiveLine(s){
  let trim=s.trim()
  let fulltrim;

  for (let i=1; i<=5; i++){
  fulltrim+="\n"+trim.repeat(i)
  
  }
  return fulltrim
}
```

When invoked, with fiveLine('a') it prints

```
undefined
aaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Besides the output 'undefined' it works perfectly like I want it to. I understand that the variable fulltrim is accessed and returned before it is updated by the for-loop, but I don't understand why. In other words, I don't understand why the output is not

```
aaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

For me, the variable fulltrim is already updated by the for-loop when returned for the first time, thus it shouldn't be undefined anymore. Thanks for reading!

Comment: The code doesn't initialise `fulltrim`. Use `let fulltrim = "";`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fulltrim` is undefined when `i` is 1, that's why it prints undefined.

initialize `fulltrim` with an empty string

```
let fulltrim = '';
```

```js
function fiveLine(s) {
  let trim = s.trim()
  let fulltrim = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    fulltrim += "\n" + trim.repeat(i)

  }
  return fulltrim
}

console.log(fiveLine('a'))
```

To prevent printing an empty line when `i` is equal to 1, you can append an empty string instead of `\n` to `fulltrim`

```js
function fiveLine(s) {
  let trim = s.trim()
  let fulltrim = '';

  for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    fulltrim += (i == 1 ? '' : "\n") + trim.repeat(i);
  }
  return fulltrim
}

console.log(fiveLine('a'))
```

#### Edit:

To understand what's really happening in your code, see the following demonstration of how value of `fulltrim` is updated in each iteration of the loop

```
// i = 1
"undefined
a"

// i = 2
"undefined
a
aa"

// i = 3
"undefined
a
aa
aaa"

// i = 4
"undefined
a
aa
aaa
aaaa"

// i = 5
"undefined
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa"
```

Comment: So basically, first the value 'fulltrim' is not initialized which is why it returns 'undefined'. But after that fulltrim is initialized with the value 'undefined' and thus it works as intended afterwards? Just trying to really understand what s going on you know. Thanks so far and to everyone else!

Comment: see the updated answer for details of how `fulltrim` is updated in each iteration

Comment: So basically 'fulltrim' gets the value 'undefined' after the first try when initializing failed. Thus the value is initialized because it has a value of 'undefined' by now? Subsequently it works as intended. I absolutely understand everything else, but wonder why the for-loop works after all. Hope you can follow my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize fulltrim.

```
 function fiveLine(s){
      let trim=s.trim()
      let fulltrim= "";
    
      for (let i=1; i<=5; i++){
      fulltrim+="\n"+trim.repeat(i)
      
      }
      return fulltrim
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- `fulltrim;` is not set to any value therefore JS treats it as `undefined`.
- To prevent the first empty line caused by the first `\n` concatenation - use `fulltrim = []` and `fulltrim.push(s.repeat(i))` instead.
- Finally return `fulltrim.join("\n");`

```js
function fiveLine(s){
  s = s.trim();
  const fulltrim = [];
  for (let i=1; i<=5; i++) fulltrim.push(s.repeat(i));
  return fulltrim.join("\n");
}

console.log(fiveLine("a"));
```

Here's another similar version:

```js
const strRepeat = (s, t) => {
  s = s.trim();
  return [...Array(t)].reduce((a, o, i) => (a.push(s.repeat(i+1)), a), []).join("\n");
}

console.log(strRepeat("a", 5));
```